# Centering Static Text WxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, center

im trying to center come statictext with boxsizers but i cant get it to center correctly

here is the relevant code:

```
hbox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.dltext = wx.StaticText(panel, label='')
self.dltext.SetFont(mfont)
self.dltext.SetForegroundColour('#FFFFFF')

hbox5.Add(self.dltext,wx.CENTER)

vbox.Add(hbox5, flag=wx.CENTER|wx.TOP, border=25)

vbox.Add((-1, 10))
```

I think its centering the corner of the text because the text starts in the middle but it goes to the right

if anyone knows how i can center it properly please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you change the text you will need to call

```
panel.Layout()
```

in order to re-center it